# How to find focal length of a single convex lens?

Tags: optics, lenses

I need help finding the focal length of a single convex lens. The radius of curvature is 200mm. left side is air and the glass has a index of 1.5. I search on google but there was only formulas for think lens, convex and converge lends. I need the formula for a single convex lens. Any idea? I know the ray transfer matrix.

$$\left(\begin{matrix}
1 & 0 \\
\frac{n-n'}{nR} & \frac{n'}{n}
\end{matrix}\right)$$

Comment: I formatted the matrix with standard TeX. Are you sure that's an $n'$ in the denominator of the lower left entry? I don't know too much about this formalism, but the [Wikipedia table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ray_transfer_matrix_analysis#Table_of_ray_transfer_matrices) has something very similar but with an $n$ there.

Comment: Thanks a lot for formatting it. You are also correct, it should be a n in the lower left. Thank you.

Comment: If this is homework, please add the homework tag.

Comment: Doesn't http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lens_(optics)#Lensmaker.27s_equation give you the equation you need?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A lens has two surfaces. One of these surfaces still has refracting power, due to the difference in refractive index and angle of incidence.

### Refraction on one surface

Let parallel rays start in glas. [Radius sign convention](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Focal_length) results $R=-200\,mm$ since incident light is on same side as center of curvature.

[image: Sketch of single refracting surface]

Radius of curvature and the two media influence the focal point. 
For your rays propagate from right to left (air) the FFL (front focal length, as depicted) is
$$f=R\cdot \frac{n_1}{n_1-n_2}=R\cdot \frac{1}{1-n_2}$$
This is the reciprocal element of your transfer matrix. Focal length is proportional to radius of curvature.  Increasing refractive index $n_2$ of glas shortens it.
$$f=-200\,mm \cdot \frac{1}{-0.5}=400\,mm$$

### Remark

The cited above [lensmaker equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lens_(optics)#Lensmaker.27s_equation) with $R_1=\infty$ will return the same result. Since on-axis parallel rays are not refracted on plane surface, as can be seen from Snell's law.